# How to display video or image in single tag?

Tags: html, angularjs

i have a drop down menu with 2 options `img` and `videos`, i have to display the data with respect to my drop down selection, so how can i achieve this please help me.

here is my HTML code :

```
<img class="cat-img" src="image path" style="width: 100px;margin: 10px 0px;"> 
or
 <video width="320" height="240" controls> <source src="videopath" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

or how can i do this using 'ng if' please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using `ng-if`

**select dropdown**

`<select ng-model='option'>
 <option value='image'>Image</option>
 <option value='video'>Video</option>
</select>`

**Change your image/video code to this**

```
 <img class="cat-img" src="image path" style="width: 100px;margin: 10px 0px;" ng-if="option=='image'"> 
 <video width="320" height="240" controls> <source src="videopath" type="video/mp4" ng-if="option=='video'"></video>
```

**If you want a single line for both this image/video better write a component for this.**

Answer (score 0):

With 'bootstrap' you could do a 'collapsible' accordion
Check this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/qq37qbdh/

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#videos">
        Videos</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="videos" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        videos section
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#images">
        Images</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="images" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Images Section
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that worked for me. Typically, your video/image is coming from a URL and is assigned to src, and in my case, they were not local and static, but rather came from IPFS, but could come from any URL. I created a simple obj array in JSON:

```
export interface media{'src': string, 'type': string}
var myMedia: media[] = [];
```

and then as I filling the 'src' part of each obj in my array, I did a little MIME check in a service function that calls a promise "mediaType"...

```
for(var x=0; x < myMedia.length; x++){
    if(myMedia[x].src!=null){
        this.mediaType(x, myMedia[x].src).then(function(data){
            myMedia[data.index].type = data.ret;
        }.bind(this)).catch( err => {
            console.log('error: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        }); 
    } else {
        myMedia[x].mediaType = null;
        //handle condition where src was null for some reason;
    }
}
```

...and here's the mediaType promise...

```
mediaType(index: number, URL: string){ 
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch(URL, {method:'HEAD'})
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(response.statusText)
            }
            var ret = response.headers.get('content-type');
            resolve({'ret': ret, 'index': index});
        },
        (err) => {
            reject({error : err});
          }
        )
    })
}
```

The index # allowed the for loop to spin ahead asynchronously, and still apply the value to the correct array element. Now inside your HTML *ngFor look, your element 'media' of myMedia can look like this...

```
<img
    class="w-full object-cover"
    [src]="media.src" *ngIf="token.mediaType!=null && token.mediaType.split('/', 2)[0]=='image'">

<video
    class="w-full object-cover" controls
    [src]="media.src" *ngIf="token.mediaType!=null && token.mediaType.split('/', 2)[0]=='video'">
</video>
```

The split will allow for any image or video MIME to work (example: image/png vs. image/jpg, or video/mp4 vs video/mov).